# How to configure SQL Server + Web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, sql-server-express

I'm new to ASP.Net and have been given access to a solution that I am currently trying to get up and running. In Web.config, I see something like this:

```
<add name="FOOBAR_Connection" connectionString="Initial Catalog=FOOBAR;Data Source=QXQDESKTOP101\SQLEXPRESS;Connect Timeout=900;Password=foo; User ID=bar;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="SiteMapConnectionString" connectionString="Initial Catalog=FOOBAR;Data Source=QXQDESKTOP101\SQLEXPRESS;Connect Timeout=900;Password=foo; User ID=bar;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Since I didn't get a database along with this solution, I am trying to create it in SQL Express. I named the DB `FOOBAR` to match what I see in the connection string. The `Data Source` was copied from the properties of the `FOOBAR` DB. I don't know how to create a `User` and `Password` for this DB. I'm hoping that once those are created and associated with the DB that I'll be able to get closer to running this application.

I think I need to create a user for the DB. Right? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: To create new log in, in your SQL Server Management Studio Expand the Server, expand security, right click on logins and click new Login.

Comment: I don't see a `Logins` option. The closest I see are `Users`. In `Users`, I can't seem to find a place to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that since you're using Express the DB resides on the same server as the app so most likely (since it seems like you haven't configured any user info) you should be able to use integrated security (similar to what's specified in the connection string here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET

Delete the User ID and Password parameters and use Integrated Security=True instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if this addresses my specific question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

if you haven't set any login details to login with sql server then you can apply this connection string

```
<add name="FOOBAR_Connection" connectionString="Initial Catalog=FOOBAR;Data Source=QXQDESKTOP101\SQLEXPRESS;Connect Timeout=900;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and if you apply login credential to sql server then you connection string will be this

```
<add name="FOOBAR_Connection" connectionString="Initial Catalog=FOOBAR;Data Source=QXQDESKTOP101\SQLEXPRESS;Connect Timeout=900;Password=foo; User ID=bar;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

to get login credential Please open you sql server management studio and in that please take Login name to userId and password to password else you can connect with first one.

Have a great day.